# Firestore rules and data structure

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a question regarding data structure and rules ... I have content on which users can vote. Something like this:

Firestore object:

```
{
  name: "Cat",
  description: "A cat named Cat",
  votes: 56
}
```

Now ... I want authenticated users to be able to have update access to the votes, but not to any other values of the object and of course read rights since the content has to be displayed.

I did this because I wanted to avoid additional queries when displaying the content.

Should I create another collection "votes" maybe where the votes are kept and for each document make an additional request to get them?

Answer (score 0):

In rules, you have access to the state of the data both before *and* after the writes - so you can test specific fields to be sure they have not changed:

```
    function existing() {
        return resource.data;
    }
    function resulting() {
        return request.resource.data;
    }
    function matchField(fieldName) {
        return existing()[fieldName] == resulting()[fieldName];
    }
....
    allow update: if matchField("name") && matchField("description")
....
```

The functions just make the rule easier to read.